# Remove all tabs of order view

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, admin

[image]

I want to remove everything which is inside the red part. All area under "**Order View**" include "**Order view**" it self. After removing this part the detail of order should start from where the "**Order view**" currently present.
I mean to say that "**Order & Account Information**" should start from where the "**Order view**" is. This will give a wide area to show the detail of order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is quite simple.

Override layout file in your module `view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="order_tab_info" destination="content"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Two things were done to achieve your desired result.

1. Page layout is changed from `admin-2columns-left` to `admin-1column`
2. Moved `order_tab_info` block from left to main block, i.e., `content`

Dont forget to clear the cache.

Result:
[image]

Comment: Hi @Ahmad, Thank you for your solution. Your solution work. However I need one more thing there. I have two admin roles. One has full access who will be able to see the tabs in order view page. The other one won't see, which is like your screenshot.